# symfony 2 exception instead message during unique validation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to display error message in symfony instead of exception  when user put duplicate name. Now it's not work and symfony displays exception.

```
/**
 * Download
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="izo_download")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\DownloadRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"name"},
 *     message="This name exist."
 * )
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Download{
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
```

Error message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   'izoplast-lato.txt' for key 'UNIQ_429C16C25E237E06'

What I do wrong?

Comment: What happens if you change `fields={"name"}` to `fields="name"` ? Also I guess you added `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;` reference as well.

Comment: Look at this example. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/d3ne/how-to-defile-unique-fileds-and-uniqueconstraint-in-doctrine

Answer (score 1):

Try with replacing `fields={"name"}` with `fields="name"`. It works for me. I've just tried. Also [check this](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/d3ne/how-to-defile-unique-fileds-and-uniqueconstraint-in-doctrine) out.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="izo_download")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="This name exist.")
 */
class Download
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have replaced fields={"name"} to fields="name", but it still throws exception ;/